# Keras model not training layers, validation accuracy always 0.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

My Keras CNN model (based on [an implementation of AlexNet](https://engmrk.com/alexnet-implementation-using-keras/)) always has training accuracy close to 0.5 (within +- 0.02) and the validation accuracy is always 0.5 exactly, no matter which epoch. It is a binary classification model where the train/val split is roughly 85/15 and within both those sets the images are split 50/50 for each class.

It doesn't seem to matter which model architecture I use, or whether I initalise with random or ImageNet weights, the validation accuracy is always 0.5. In fact, when I didn't have the images split 50/50 into their binary classifications, the validation accuracy would reflect this (so when I had significantly more images belonging to one class, the validation accuracy would always be 0.85).

Because of this last point, I have a suspicion the problem doesn't lie with the model or weight optimisation, but rather with my instantiation of the ImageDataGenerator class - although this is just an educated hunch at this stage.

I've included my code below, can anyone locate any blindingly obvious errors?

```
sz=224 # image width = height = 224
batch_size=64
train_data_dir = r"./crack_dataset/train"
validation_data_dir = r"./crack_dataset/validate"
nb_train_samples = 3416
nb_val_samples = 612

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                    target_size = (sz, sz),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                              target_size = (sz, sz),
                                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              class_mode='binary')

# Create Model 
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.1), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size, 
                    epochs=30,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=nb_val_samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: It looks like the last Dense layer is quickly settling to either 1/0. Have you tried changing the last activation to ReLU or some such function?

Comment: @Kalpit That is this purpose of the last Dense layer, since this is binary classification problem we want the final layer to output either 1 or 0.

Comment: You might want to set the learning rate of Adam to a lower value, something like 0.001

Comment: Do not use Adam to train AlexNet, prefer SGD, as Adam has troubles with large networks.

Comment: @Igna yes that's it, thank you! Moving fine now at 10e-6, so I'll play around with different LRs + also change to SGD as suggested in another comment.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Okay thanks for the advice, I didn't know that. I'll implement that change and also decrease the LR as suggested in another comment.

Comment: @jgk_iles done, :) if you wish for more of an explanation, just ask and I'll add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the learning rate of the optimizer, the value is way too big. 
As suggested in the comment, it should be set to a low value, close to 0.

You can see how the learning rate might influence the classification accuracy in the image below:

[image: example of how the learning rate influences the performance of a model]

Answer (score -2):

It was a comment, but too long so I switched to a proper answer.

I haven't tried your CNN, but I would revise your layers. I'm not an expert in designing CNN architectures but I don't see a lot of meaning in having 2 layers in a row with the same parameters (5th and 6th layers), it's pretty useless for what I've learned so far. Try with some simple architecture and "scale up" (in terms of complexity of the architecture) from there.

Furthermore, going up and down in terms of "number of units" ( 1st, 3rd, 5th, 6th, 7th layers, Conv2D) might not be the best strategy, everytime you go up you generalize in terms of features to get because you start from less features, you are asking to your network to create features from a smaller set. There are some scenarios where it might be useful, but I don't think this is one of them.

And for the rescaling you don't need to call "ImageDataGenerator", you can reach the same result with:

`train_datagen = train_datagen/255.0`

Simplify where you can.

Comment: I'll edit my original post to highlight: this network is [an implementation of AlexNet](https://engmrk.com/alexnet-implementation-using-keras/) which is well established as a reasonable, if simple, CNN architecture. Also, like I said in my original post, the accuracy/validation accuracy are blind to the network - it's **always** 0.5. As to your last point, it is not possible to instantiate train_datagen in that way.

Comment: Btw: AlexNet performs way better on a multi class problem, it was created not for a binary classification problem.

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect your first point. The -1 was not mine as I don't have enough community reputation for that to display anyway! I'll have a look at changing to a network better suited for binary classification, cheers.

Comment: Cheers to you, hope you'll find a better architecture, keep us updated with that! Then let me puntualize that users who downgrade answers without explaining are the best. LoL